# Is there an equivalent to python's urllib in c/c++?

Tags: c++, python, url

any c/c++ library out there that provides functions like getUrl, urlopen, post etc. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some libraries, [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and [libwww](http://www.w3.org/Library/) amongst others.

`libcurl` website even lists some other [alternatives](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not a batteries-included, officially endorsed library, but there are numerous libraries out there. The most popular, AFAIK, is [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), which I've used to good effect in the past. It has an "easy" interface, which really is easy to use (though definitely not as easy as Python's urllib).